# NEI won't show alchemical chest recipe

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I have recently got the tekkit mod for minecraft. I'm playing on the latest versions of both tekkit and minecraft. I'm using the NEI mod, and have it switched to recipe mode. Basic crafting works fine for the recipe mode, for instance I can view the recipe for an emerald transport pipe. But the alchemical chest recipe will not display. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alchemical chest from Equivalent Exchange 3 simply doesn't have a recipe. It's still in the code, but it's slated to be removed, and hasn't functioned since EE2.

Comment: Thank you! Will any other important things be affected? In particular, will I still be able to craft the energy condenser?

Comment: @impulsion The condenser and most other things no longer exist. I know! Everyone is mourning the loss of EE2, but it's been declared dead due to a change of author and no permission for others to continue it. EE3 aims to be a complete redesign, but right now all it adds is a craftable damagable philosopher's stone replacement called a Minium Stone.